# Why does declaring an int array of length INT_MAX create a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

The following code, when compiled and run, gives me a segmentation fault. Why is this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
  int fat_array[INT_MAX];

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your system, that time, did not have enough memory for a _local_ array that big.  It tried and failed at run time.

Comment: stackoverflow without the .com

Comment: You'd need 8 GiB of stack space for `int fat_array[INT_MAX]`; Unix-like systems are generous and normally give you 8 _MiB_ of stack space; Windows is more conservative and normally only gives you 1 MiB.  Either way, it's massively less space than needed.  Either allocate the array at file scope (outside `main()`), or use dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()` et al).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are requesting is to have about `2,147,483,647`integer spaces allocated to you. Each integer is usually four bytes so that's `8,589,934,588` bytes which is 8 gigabytes of memory. This is likely above the allowed amount of memory a single process is allowed to reserve, and for good reason, so you get an error.

Comment: It's slightly misleading to say "above the allowed amount of memory a single process is allowed to reserve". If it were to be heap allocted and the system has
enough it's fine to use to reserve/allocate as much and there's no general limit for memory. The specific problem here is that it's "stack" allocated (aka automatic storage).